# DataFrame print raises Shapely Deprecation Warning (Iteration over multi-part geometries...) when MultiPolygon in DataFrame cell

Tags: pandas, dataframe, warnings, shapely

1. Create a dataframe with 1 col and 1 row
   Input:

```
data = [[[12.9883, 52.7281],
         [12.9883, 52.2658],
         [13.8967, 52.2658],
         [13.8967, 52.7281],
         [12.9883, 52.7281]]]
df = pd.DataFrame({'new_coords': [data]})
```

Output:

```
None
```

2. Print dataframe:
   Input:

```
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                          new_coords
0  [[[12.9883, 52.7281], [12.9883, 52.2658], [13....
```

3. Add a new column which creates a mulitpolygon from list of lists of coordinates:
   Input:

```
df['new_shape'] = df['new_coords'].apply(lambda x: MultiPolygon([Polygon(i) for i in x]))
```

Output:

```
None
```

4. Print dataframe:
   Input:

```
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                          new_coords  \
0  [[[12.9883, 52.7281], [12.9883, 52.2658], [13....   

                                           new_shape  
0  (POLYGON ((12.9883 52.7281, 12.9883 52.2658, 1...

C:\Users\k9343\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\inference.py:397: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: Iteration over multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms` property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry.
  iter(obj)  # Can iterate over it.
C:\Users\k9343\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\inference.py:398: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: __len__ for multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Check the length of the `geoms` property instead to get the  number of parts of a multi-part geometry.
  len(obj)  # Has a length associated with it.
C:\Users\k9343\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\printing.py:115: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: Iteration over multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms` property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry.
  s = iter(seq)
C:\Users\k9343\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\printing.py:119: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: __len__ for multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Check the length of the `geoms` property instead to get the  number of parts of a multi-part geometry.
  for i in range(min(nitems, len(seq)))
C:\Users\k9343\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\printing.py:123: ShapelyDeprecationWarning: __len__ for multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Check the length of the `geoms` property instead to get the  number of parts of a multi-part geometry.
  if nitems < len(seq):
```

5. Do the same outside of the dataframe:
   Input:

```
i = 0
new_coords = df['new_coords'][i]
x = new_coords
new_shape = MultiPolygon([Polygon(i) for i in x])
print(new_shape)
```

Output:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((12.9883 52.7281, 12.9883 52.2658, 13.8967 52.2658, 13.8967 52.7281, 12.9883 52.7281)))
```

Is there a way of not triggering the warnings other than suppressing them?

```
print(pd.__version__)
2.1.1
print(shapely.__version__)
1.8.4
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The typical way to use DataFrames with a Geometry column is to use GeoDataFrames from [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/)... and then you normally avoid having this warning.